# Java library to match characters against a given language

Tags: java

Is there a java library that will allow me to test whether a given set of characters match against a given language code or not? I need as many languages that can be supported as possible.
Something like:

```
boolean matches(String characters, String language)
```

For Ex:

```
matches("Español", "Spanish") -> true
matches("зовут", "Russian") -> true
matches("зовут", "English") -> false
```

Comment: Like http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Language-Guess/lib/Text/Language/Guess.pm but in Java?

Comment: Do you want to check whether `characters` is a translation or whether the characters are used in a language's alphabet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Java library for automatic language identification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395478/best-java-library-for-automatic-language-identification)

Comment: @Thomas: I want to check whether the characters are used in a language's alphabet. Basically the language can be any one from this list: http://www.verisigninc.com/assets/idn-valid-language-tags.pdf

Comment: Slightly off topic: you should be aware that people using some languages (e.g. German, Polish) sometimes tend to replace letters with diacritics with other letter sequences with the same pronunciation (e.g. "für" => "fuer") or even drop diacritics altogether (e.g. "się" => "sie"). Hence, you should not rely on alphabet only to detect language. I guess you can still use it in some heuristics.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395478/best-java-library-for-automatic-language-identification

Search in the net for "**java language indentification**"

Answer (score 1):

This might help you: [How can I determine what the alphabet for a locale is in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417377/how-can-i-determine-what-the-alphabet-for-a-locale-is-in-java)

Basically you need to get the characters used in a language's alphabet and then check whether all of the characters in your input are contained in your set. Note, however, that this might yield wrong results, since for example, all English characters are used in German as well and for short texts the probability for a German text using only those charaters (i.e. no ä,ö,ü or ß) is quite high.