# Android how to get alphabet of locale

Tags: android, locale

I want to show whole alphabet of current or selected locale.

Is it possible to do?

Something like

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3521680/849961

But this in java, how to get in Android?

Comment: Android IS Java ...take a look at all the Packages in the Reference at http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

Comment: Yeah it's java, thank K.O., i just want to say "if android has default methods for get alphabet"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so it's possible. In any case Locale in android has no similar method like in java.